# how to use Birt Report in Spring

Tags: java, report, birt

### Hello , I am using Spring Framework to Develop a web app(in J2EE).

Here i need to Make some Reports.

Now i am using Birt Report for Making Reports.

I have created one report (in **Birt**) but i don't know how to add it on my current project.

[image: Sale Report in Birt]

#### so, please help me..please give me some  ***examples***...

please......Thanks in Advance.....

Comment: This question shows little attempt to solve the problem on your own, you should read [this FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of links on BIRT page: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Integration_Examples_%28BIRT%29

Especially you should be interested in following ones:

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/Servlet_Example_%28BIRT%29_2.1 - servlet examples
- http://wiki.eclipse.org/Simple_Execute_%28BIRT%29_2.1 - running BIRT as Java application
- http://wiki.eclipse.org/Java_-_Dynamic_Report_Servlet_%28BIRT%29 - Dynamic report servlet

Let us know if that helps.

Comment: Answers based primarly on links are discouraged.  But at the same time this question is so overly broad that, more detailed answers would be difficult.